# How to flatten 2D array to 1D array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I flatten the 2 dimensions array `int originalArray[][]` to 1 dimension array?

```
    int a [] = {1,2,6,7,2};
    int b [] = {2,44,55,2};
    int c [] = {2,44,511,33};

    int originalArray [][] = new int[][]{a,b,c};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple for loop will do, it is not difficult, but will depend on the order in which you want to copy the values. For instance (based on the fact that in your example the arrays all have the same length):

```
int[] newArray = new int[3 * a.length];
int index = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < a.length; n++) {
    newArray[index++] = a[n];
    newArray[index++] = b[n];
    newArray[index++] = c[n];
}
```

or (different order, a, b, c can be of different lengths):

```
int[] newArray = new int[a.length + b.length + c.length];
System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, a.length);
System.arraycopy(b, 0, newArray, a.length, b.length);
System.arraycopy(c, 0, newArray, a.length + b.length, c.length);
```

Comment: The example arrays don't have the same length. a.length == 5, b.length == 4, c.length == 4.

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning that the two examples end up with different orderings for the final flattened array, if that matters.  In the first example, the arrays are 'weaved', while in the second, they are placed 'end-to-end', if that makes sense

Comment: @Kevin, I think I did mention that: `different order, a, b, c can be of different lengths`

Answer (score 46):

With [Guava](https://guava.dev/), you can use either

`int[] all = Ints.concat(originalArray);`

or

`int[] all = Ints.concat(a, b, c);`

Comment: Downvoted why?  Who wants to write all that code above when they need to do this?

Comment: Is there any method to do the same for an array of Objects?

Comment: `ObjectArrays.concat`

Answer (score 44):

With Java 8 you can "flatMap" the inner arrays:

```
int[] flatArray = Arrays.stream(originalArray)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray();
```

or:

```
int[] flatArray = Stream.of(a, b, c)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .toArray();
```

Answer (score 4):

There will be 2 steps:

1) find out total number of elements to create a new vector (1d array)

2) iterate through your 2d array in predefined order and copy its elements to the created vector

```
int elementsNumber = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
   elementsNumber += originalArray[i].length;
}

int[] newArray = new int[elementsNumber];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
   System.arrayCopy (originalArray[i], 0, newArray, j, originalArray[i].length);
   j += originalArray[i].length;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] oneDArray = new int[arr.length*arr.length];
    //Flatten 2D array to 1D array...
    int s = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) 
          for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j ++){                           
              oneDArray[s] = arr[i][j];
              s++;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays can't be extended (i.e. you have to declare the size of an error upon initialization), you have to traverse the arrays twice:

```
int size = 0;
for (int[] ar : originalArray) size += ar.length;
int[] result = new int[size];
int pos = 0;
for (int[] ar : originalArray) {
    System.arraycopy(ar, 0, result, pos, ar.length);
    pos += ar.length;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm quite surprised recursion isn't necessary.

Comment: is it possible not to use loop?

Comment: @Jessy Well, you could use recursion, but that would it make way messier and slower.

Comment: I think, I should use arraycopy :-)

Comment: Note: though it wasn't specified as a requirement, with this technique, there's no way to return to the original arrays without retaining their lengths. The solution by @rsp is close a technique capable of reversing the process. Just pointing out that the requirements of the flattening will dictate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

*one-liner with* `IntStream`

```
IntStream.concat(
    IntStream.concat( IntStream.of(originalArray[0]), IntStream.of(originalArray[1]) ),
        IntStream.of(originalArray[2]) ).toArray();
```

gets: `[1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 2, 44, 55, 2, 2, 44, 511, 33]`

Answer (score 0):

below code can merge varied 2D arrays (diff sizes of internal array) into a one dimensional array:

```
 public static Integer[] merge2DArrays(int[][] twoDArray){
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
                list.add(twoDArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
    return list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Count the total number of elements in originalArray.  Create new array of that length.  Copy elements one by one into the new array.

I am unfamiliar with any library function to do so.