# matrix to array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

Which would be the most efficient way to convert a squared matrix like

```
  1 2 3 
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

into

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

in c#

I was doing

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
int[] array1D = new int[9];
int ci=0;

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      {
            array1D[ci++] = array2D[i, j]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: [This][1] seems to be the same questions, answered. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569279/how-to-flatten-2d-array-to-1d-array

Comment: @Olexsi it's not quite the same; this question uses a proper 2-dimensional array, while the one you linked to is asking about a 2-dimensional jagged array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always better off allocating the complete result array in one hit, then copying the data in.

You should find the total size like this;

```
var size = arrays.Sum(a=> a.Length);
var result = new int[size];
```

And then copy the arrays using Array.CopyTo, instead of looping yourself;

```
var cursor = 0;
foreach(var a in arrays) {
   a.CopyTo(result, cursor);
   cursor += a.Length;    
}
```

Array.CopyTo will be faster than your own loop; at least, not slower. It will probably use [C's memcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) function internally to do a low-level block copy. This is as efficient as you can be.

Answer (score 8):

LINQ makes this trivial.

```
int[,] array2d = ...;
var array1d = array2d.Cast<int>().ToArray();
```

Otherwise, your way is adequate but could be generalized:

```
int[,] array2d = ...;
var rows = array2d.GetLength(0);
var cols = array2d.GetLength(1);
var array1d = new int[rows * cols];
var current = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        array1d[current++] = array2d[i, j];
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
int[,] array2d = ...;
var array1d = new int[array2d.GetLength(0) * array2d.GetLength(1)];
var current = 0;
foreach (var value in array2d)
{
    array1d[current++] = value;
}
```

Comment: Which one is faster and less resource consumption ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't profiled it myself.  But I'd suspect the third version would be the fastest.

Comment: what abt LINQ ? It will fast I hope

Comment: It appears the second one is actually fastest with the third coming in pretty close within ~120ms.  The first version coming in the slowest 55 times slower than the fastest in my tests.  One million iterations converting a 10x10 matrix.  `time ms (ticks)`: `27349ms (75675449)`, `491ms (1359839)`, `614ms (1700921)`.

Comment: @JeffMercado in the first example, there's no need to call .Cast<int>() as the elements are already ints.

Comment: @phoog: But multidimensional arrays only implement the non-generic  `IEnumerable` interface.  The cast is necessary to be able to use LINQ there.

Comment: aha, I didn't know that.  Thanks for the information.  That also explains the poorer performance because of the boxing.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff said, LINQ makes this trivial. `OfType<>()` should generally be a little faster than `Cast<>` though:

```
array1D = array2D.OfType<int>().ToArray();
```

The implementation of `OfType<>` however will still suffer from boxing/unboxing penalties, as @phoog mentioned.

Just for the fun of it, if you want a fast LINQ-based solution (avoiding the cost of boxing) you could use this small extension method:

```
static class LinqEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T[,] matrix)
    {
        foreach (var item in matrix) yield return item;
    }
}
```

Or this, based on Jeff's 2nd solution:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> Flatten<T>(this T[,] matrix)
    {
        var rows = matrix.GetLength(0);
        var cols = matrix.GetLength(1);
        for (var i = 0; i < rows;i++ )
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++ )
                yield return matrix[i, j];
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
 int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };  
 int[] array1D = array2D.Flatten().ToArray();
```

I didn't fully profile this but I expect this will get you much better performance than the built-in options based on LINQ/IEnumerable. Jeff's second solution will however always be the fasted, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using [Buffer.BlockCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
int[] array1D = new int[ array2D.Length ];
Buffer.BlockCopy(array2D, 0, array1D, 0, array1D.Length * sizeof(int));
```