# How to save a 2-D array value to a 1-D array

Tags: java, android

how to pass the value of a 2-d array index to a 1-d array index in android?I want to place this code inside a switch case.

`int r1[]= int M[0][0];`

Comment: Just to undertstand: You have a 2D array (for example 3x4) and you want to put all values in a 1D array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten 2D array to 1D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569279/how-to-flatten-2d-array-to-1d-array)

Comment: no i want to add specific 2-d elements to 1-d arrays. `case R.id.b1:
                int r1=M[0][0];
                B1.setClickable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.b2:
                [1][0];
                int c2=M[1][0];
                B1.setClickable(false);
                break;` something like this @Blobonat

Answer (score 0):

You want to **flatten** the array

Dependent on what version you are using these are a couple options!

Using Java 8 Streams:

```
int[] r1= Stream.of(M).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
```

Older versions of Java:

```
int[] r1 = new int[size];
int index = 0;
for (int[] x: M) {    // loop through the rows
    for (int y: x)    // loop through the values
        array[index++] = y;
}
```

Dynamically allocating the values using an ArrayList is an option:

```
ArrayList<int> r1 = new ArrayList<>();
case R.id.b1:
    int val=M[0][0]; 
    r1.add(val);
```

Comment: I want to pass specific values in specific cases `case R.id.b1:
                int r1=M[0][0];
                B1.setClickable(false);
                break;
            case R.id.b2:
                [1][0];
                int c2=M[1][0];
                B1.setClickable(false);
                break;` is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: So maybe an ArrayList would be the better option here as you can dynamically allocate values this way and it won't be necessary to assign a fixed value to the array @beard_beer_code

Comment: How would that go? any help would be appreciated @Small Legend