# Convert 2-dimensional array into 1-dimensional

Tags: java

I'm struggling with this quite a while, how can i convert the first line into the second? Thanks very much in advance!

```
int mm [] [] = new int[][] {{10, 30},{30, 5},{5,60}};
int mm [] = new int[] {10, 30, 5, 60};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to flatten 2D array to 1D array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569279/how-to-flatten-2d-array-to-1d-array)

Comment: Are you using java 8?

Comment: `Arrays.stream(mm).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).distinct().toArray()`

Comment: You are converting three elements into four? What is the algorithm you are thinking of? Seems like you are collapsing similar numbers?

Comment: These are 3 matrices with the dimensions 10x30,30x5,5x60. The input needs to be in the form of line 1 and should then convert to the form of line 2 in order to make my programm work.